# Android app with test flag

Tags: java, android

I want to run the same android code, but select test server or production server at runtime based on some setting.

My first idea was to detect if my IP address is a "10.x.x.x" address and run according which is working, but it occurs to me that my live users may want to run on their 10. network too and thus break my app.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Try with your device id it's unique for each device I guess

Comment: That is what build types are for. Use `buildConfigField` to define fields on `BuildConfig`, where you provide different values for `debug` and `release` builds.

Answer (score 1):

I would use flavors. i.e you can use "mock" and "prod" flavor

Answer (score 0):

I guess that will work for your scenrio

Try with your device id it's unique for devices